# List changed and dependent modules

Tags: git, maven, gradle

I am trying to set up a CI-CD pipeline. In this pipeline, each commit should run a bunch of tests. Since the project is a multi-module setup, I would like to run tests only for the modules impacted. For this I need to identify the following:

A. From the files changed, identify the modules that have been impacted.

B. Once a list of modules is found, find all the modules that depend on these modules.

C. Run tests for all the modules found in step B.

Currently, I can get the list of files changed using git. But once I have the list of files, is there an easy way either in mvn/gradle to get the list of modules modified and the modules that are dependent on these modules?

Comment: Which CI/CD system do you use? The answers will also depend on this. But in general speaking: Getting the dependencies will be hard...

Comment: Jenkins clubbed with gerrit is the pipeline. Did not find anything that runs by default.

Comment: With jenkins it should be possible to create a single project for each (maven) module and then it is possible to use a feature from the maven project template to let jenkins resolve the dependencies.